Group By and check if the group contains
I have houses that can have fixtures 'Sink, 'Faucet' and/or 'Toilet'.
I want find which houses have at least one fixture from the list, but are  missing other fixtures and return the missing fixtures.
I have all the required fixtures in a separate list and not in the database.
For example, if the house has only a sink, I would like to know that it is missing a faucet and a toilet.
Data and Results
Data



House
Fixture




1
Sink


1
Faucet


1
Toilet


2
Sink


2
Faucet


3
Sink



Results



House
Missing Fixture




2
Toilet


3
Faucet


3
Toilet




so many if or nested if in your question, that the expectation is not clear.

Please provide enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios and the result you want to achieve based on that data - all as editable text formatted as tables. Also, please format your code as code so that it is readable

please explain about your desired output. it is not clear. show your desired output in table

Also - what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

one solution is to create a cross join table of all houses and all fixtures, then left join it with input table.
enter co
WITH All_Fixtures as (
  SELECT distinct Fixture FROM Data ),
Houses as (
  SELECT distinct House FROM Data )
SELECT Houses.House , All_Fixtures.Fixture 
  FROM Houses CROSS JOIN All_Fixtures
  LEFT JOIN Data 
    ON Houses.House = Data.House AND All_Fixtures.Fixture = Data.Fixture
    WHERE Data.Fixture IS NULL 
    ORDER BY Houses.House;

It will work even if some fixture is added to our table.
input data is created by this query:
-- create 
CREATE TABLE Data (
  House NUMBER,
  Fixture VARCHAR2(10)
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (1, 'Sink');
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (1, 'Faucet');
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (1, 'Toilet');
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (2, 'Sink');
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (2, 'Faucet');
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (3, 'Sink');


You missed to filter to houses "... which have at least one fixture from the list ...". One fixture that is not in the list will make this resultset quite messy.

EDITED ANSWER  (after the question was edited)
Create a cte using Case expressions to get all 3 fixtures in the row with the ID and UNION ALL the rows with missing fixtures...
Oracle:
Create Table table1      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
     AS
      ( Select 1 as ID, 'Sink' as FIXTURE From Dual Union All 
        Select 1, 'Faucet' From Dual Union All 
        Select 1, 'Toilet' From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, 'Sink' From Dual Union All 
        Select 2, 'Faucet' From Dual Union All 
        Select 3, 'Sink' From Dual Union All
        Select 4, 'WiFi' From Dual
      );

WITH
  grid AS
      ( Select    t1.ID, 
                   Max(Case When t1.FIXTURE = 'Faucet' Then 1 Else 0 End) as FAUCET,
                   Max(Case When t1.FIXTURE = 'Sink' Then 1 Else 0 End) as SINK,
                   Max(Case When t1.FIXTURE = 'Toilet' Then 1 Else 0 End) as TOILET
        From      table1 t1
        Where     t1.FIXTURE IN('Faucet', 'Sink', 'Toilet')
        Group By  t1.ID
      )

--    S Q L :
Select ID, 'Faucet' as MISSING_FIXTURE From grid Where FAUCET = 0 Union All
Select ID, 'Sink' as MISSING_FIXTURE From grid Where SINK = 0 Union All
Select ID, 'Toilet' as MISSING_FIXTURE From grid Where TOILET = 0 
Order By ID

/*   R e s u l t :
ID  MISSING_FIXTURE
--  ---------------
 2  Toilet
 3  Faucet
 3  Toilet         */

fiddle here
ANSWER BEFORE QUESTION WAS EDITED
One option is to compare your group of fixtures to a list of table fixtures per House ID. The creation of the latter depends on rdbms you are using (LISTAGG() for Oracle, GROUP_CONCAT() for MySql, STRING_AGG() for Postgres, ...)
... define your group of fixtures to compare to ...
WITH      -- G r o u p    d e f i n i t i o n :
  fixture_group ( GROUP_ID, FIXTURE_GROUP) AS 
       ( Select 1, 'Faucet, Sink, Toilet' as FIXTURE From Dual )

... compare lists and remove existing fixtures from the group, comma characters and leading/trailing space characters. If null is left then nothing is missing ( '-' ) ...
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    Distinct t1.ID, 
          TRIM( REPLACE(
          COALESCE( REPLACE( fg.FIXTURE_GROUP, 
                               LISTAGG(t1.FIXTURE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP 
                               (Order By t1.FIXTURE) Over(Partition By t1.ID), 
                            ''), 
                  '-'),
         ',', '') ) as MISSING_FIXTURE_LIST
From      table1 t1
Inner Join fixture_group fg ON( INSTR(fg.FIXTURE_GROUP, t1.FIXTURE) > 0 )
Order By  t1.ID;

/*    R e s u l t : 
ID  MISSING_FIXTURE_LIST
--  --------------------
 1  -
 2  Toilet
 3  Faucet  Toilet        */


Use a join to find houses with at least one fixture, a cross join to generate all the combos, and finally a left join (filtering for non-matches) to find the missing fixtures:
with fixtures as (
  select 'Faucet' fixture from dual union
  select 'Sink' from dual union
  select 'Toilet' from dual
), house_ids_with_fixtures as (
  select distinct h.id
  from house_fixture h
  join fixtures f on f.fixture = h.fixture
)
select x.*
from (select * from house_ids_with_fixtures cross join fixtures) x
left join house_fixture h on h.id = x.id and h.fixture = x.fixture
where h.id is null
order by 1, 2

See live demo.

For the fun you can also do it with MULTISET, as long as you define STRING_T as a TABLE OF VARCHAR2(choose_len_you_need):
with house_fixture(id, fixture) as (
  select 1, 'Sink' From Dual Union  
  select 1, 'Faucet' From Dual Union  
  select 1, 'Toilet' From Dual Union  
  select 2, 'Sink' From Dual Union  
  select 2, 'Faucet' From Dual Union  
  select 3, 'Sink' From Dual Union 
  select 4, 'WiFi' From Dual
)
, fixtures(fixture) as (
  select 'Faucet' from dual union
  select 'Sink' from dual union
  select 'Toilet' from dual
)
, sets(id, diff) as (
    select id, diff from (
        select 
            id,
            (
            cast(multiset (select fixture from fixtures) as string_t)
            multiset except
            cast(multiset (select fixture from house_fixture hf1 where hf1.id = hf.id) as string_t)
            ) as diff
        from 
            house_fixture hf
        group by id
    )
    where cardinality(diff) between 1 and (select count(*)-1 from fixtures) 
)
select s.id, t.column_value 
from sets s, table(s.diff) t
;


Use a PARTITIONed OUTER JOIN to find the missing fixtures and analytic functions to count the existing fixtures in each group:
WITH fixtures (fixture) AS (
  SELECT 'Sink'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Faucet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Toilet' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id,
       fixture
FROM   (
  SELECT t.id,
         f.fixture,
         t.fixture AS has_fixture,
         COUNT(t.fixture) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS num_fixtures
  FROM   fixtures f
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY (t.id)
         ON (f.fixture = t.fixture)
)
WHERE  num_fixtures > 0
AND    has_fixture IS NULL;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, fixture) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Sink'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 'Faucet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 'Toilet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'Sink'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'Faucet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Sink'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'WiFi'   FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
FIXTURE




2
Toilet


3
Faucet


3
Toilet



fiddle
